# How to use multiple csv file in jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I want to use 2 csv files in my jmeter script. One file having app URL, username and password information. Second csv is having input data for my test.

URL.csv having app URL data( this might be 1 url for whole test)
Data.csv having id, name etc

I am able to run my test using single csv file but the requirement is to use separate csv file for Config elements like URL,username , password etc and separate csv file for Input data for test. Please help

Answer (score -1):

C'mon, just add 2 [CSV Data Set Config elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and point them to different CSV files. Make sure that the JMeter Variables defined in the CSV files have different/unique names otherwise they will be overwritten.

There is only one limitation: you cannot use a variable from CSV file #1 as a filename (or a part of filename) for CSV file #2, if you need to setup a data relationships between 2 CSV files - you will have to go for [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function instead, see [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) article for more details.

Comment: sorry but the question was using 2 csv files for same http sampler. Its easy to use 2 csv for 2 different http request. but i have to use 2 csv for same http request. i hope its more clear now

Comment: @dmitri, you were not answering the question.